# Running a custom built npm package not working

Tags: node.js, npm-install, package.json

I am building an npm library and published it to npm.
After publishing I am trying to install the library globally.
But it's not working, looks like it's trying to open the file directly

My package.json looks like as follows:

```
{
  "name": "lssomename",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "index.js",


  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "command-line-args": "^5.0.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "zip-folder": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

As soon as I try to run it throws the following error

```
/home/thabung/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/lssomename: line 1: $'\r': command not found
/home/thabung/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/lssomename: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'home/thabung/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/lssomename: line 2: `const log = require("./logger");
```

The same error comes if try to run directly the `index.js` file, meaning
when I try

`./index.js`

instead of

```
node index.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was, I need to add an indicator in the begining of the file,
also known as [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for Unix like systems like as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

in the beginning of my `index.js` file & it started working after that.